# Angular 2 + Jira, set header cookie

Tags: javascript, angular, jira, session-cookies, jira-rest-api

I'm building a Angular 2 app that will connect to a Jira server and post issues (CORS is configured at the server).

I've managed to login to the server via the REST API and I get the session details when I log in, but now I need to supply them with my requests. It says that I'm not authenticated.

I've unsuccessfully tried to add them in the headers like the example in the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-cookie-based-authentication#JIRARESTAPIExample-Cookie-basedAuthentication-Step2.Usethesessioncookieinarequest):

```
headers.append('cookie', this.sessionName + '=' + this.sessionId);
```

> DELETE http:// (Jira server) /rest/auth/1/session 401 (Unauthorized)

Logout function as example:

```
//set in login function (example response: "session":{"name":"JSESSIONID","value":"<session value>"})
sessionName: string;
sessionValue: string;

logout() {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('cookie', this.sessionName + '=' + this.sessionValue);

  this.http.delete(`http://(Jira server)/rest/auth/1/session`, headers)
  .subscribe(
    (res: Response) => {
      this.loggedin = false;
      console.log('Logged out');
    },
    err => console.log(err),
  );
}
```

How can I add add the session details to a header cookie to supply it with my requests?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure your cookie hasn't expired yet? perhaps you need to re-authenticate using `AUTH`

Comment: I call the logout function directly after logging in, so the session should still be valid.

Comment: but doesn't logout invalidate your cookie...?

Comment: The problem is that I can't get the session cookie to the server. So basically I can't logout since the server doesn't know which cookie to delete until I can add it to my request.